# Change Calculator not showing change

Tags: java, class

This is my first time taking a java class and for my assignment am suppose to write a Class and Driver to show the change that is returned as well as the coins.
i.e Enter item price: 45.50 -> Enter cash given: 50.00 -> Change is 4.50 -> dollars: 4 & quarters: 2

Here is the class.

```
public class Change 
{
    private int price;
    private int cash;

public Change (int p, int c)  { price =p; cash =c; }

public Change() {
}

public int getPrice ( ) { return price;} 

public void setPrice (int p) {price=p;}

public int getCash ( ) { return cash;}

public void setCash (int c) {cash=c;}

    public int computeChange( ) {return cash-price; }
    public int toDollars ( ) {return computeChange() / 100; }
    public int aChanges ( ) {return computeChange() % 100; }
    public int toQuarters ( ) {return aChanges() / 25; }
    public int bChanges ( ) {return aChanges() % 25; }
    public int toDimes ( ) {return bChanges() / 10; }
    public int cChanges ( ) {return bChanges() % 10; }
    public int toNickels ( ) {return cChanges() / 5; }  
    public int dChanges ( ) {return cChanges() % 5; }   
    public int toPennies ( ) {return dChanges() / 1; }
    public int eChanges (  ) {return dChanges() % 1; }      
   }
```

Here is my driver

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TestChange{

   public static void main (String[] args)
   {

    double cash;
    double price;
    double changes = 0;
    int change;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

   Change c = new Change ();

   System.out.println ("Enter the price of the item: ");
   price = scan.nextDouble();

   System.out.println ("Enter cash amount: ");
   cash = scan.nextDouble();
   int cents = (int) (changes * 100);

   changes = c.computeChange();

   System.out.println ("Change: " + changes );

System.out.println ("Dollar bills is: " + c.toDollars());
System.out.println ("Quarters is: " + c.toQuarters());
System.out.println ("Dimes is: " + c.toDimes());
System.out.println ("Nickels is: " + c.toNickels());
System.out.println ("Pennies is: " + c.toPennies());
   }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I guess there's something wrong with your code, but could you be more specific and tell us what exactly are you having problems with?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're not using `price` and `cash` when you create your `Change` object.  You need to use the constructor for the `Change` object, where you specify the price in cents, and the cash tendered in cents.

Remove the line

```
Change c = new Change ();
```

and replace the line

```
int cents = (int)(changes * 100);
```

with  a  new line

```
Change c = new Change ((int)(price * 100 + 0.5), (int)(cash * 100 + 0.5));
```

That way, you're making the `Change` object from the numbers that the user has entered; and also multiplying everything by 100 to turn it into a number of cents.  The extra `0.5` is because you sometimes get a rounding error if you use a `double` variable to store an amount of money, because `double` variables don't generally store decimal numbers accurately - depending on how  you use them, it can be a bad idea to use them for money.

Comment: Thanks for the help David! I did what you said to do but i am still unable to get the change to appear. It is still showing 0 for my change.

Comment: OK, I can't see why.  Incidentally, I just corrected a small error in the code above - but it was an error that would have prevented the code from compiling, not one that would have given you incorrect output.  Can you try using your debugger to stop execution after the `Change` object has been created, and just check that it has the `price` and `cash` fields set correctly?  That will give information about what's actually going wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm fairly new to this. I'm using eclipse and I'm not sure how the debugger option works.

Comment: OK.  My honest opinion is that using a debugger is one of the most important skills a new programmer can learn.  If you're going to be a professional programmer, it will save you YEARS of time, over the course of your career.  So the best advice I can give you would be LEARN NOW.  If you don't want to do that, then just add a couple of lines to the constructor to print out the two arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work.

Change summary -

1. Cange type of price and cash to double from int in class "Change" and change the getter,  setter and constructor accordingly
2. Create object of class "Change" using parameterized constructor.
3. you may have to change the method body of class "Change" accordingly as the type of member variables are changed from int to double. But I guess you get the idea.

   ```
   import java.text.DecimalFormat;
   import java.util.Scanner;

   public class TestChange{

   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
   double cash;
   double price;
   double changes = 0;
   DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

   Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

   System.out.println ("Enter the price of the item: ");
   price = scan.nextDouble();

   System.out.println ("Enter cash amount: ");
   cash = scan.nextDouble();

   Change c = new Change (price,cash);
   changes = c.computeChange();

   System.out.println ("Change: " + df.format(changes) );
   System.out.println ("Dollar bills is: " + c.toDollars());
   System.out.println ("Quarters is: " + c.toQuarters());
   System.out.println ("Dimes is: " + c.toDimes());
   System.out.println ("Nickels is: " + c.toNickels());
   System.out.println ("Pennies is: " + c.toPennies());
   }
   }


   class Change 
   {
   private double price;
   private double cash;

   public Change (double p, double c)  
   { 
   this.price =p; 
   this.cash =c; 
   }

   public Change() 
   {
   }

   public double getPrice ( ) { return this.price;} 
   public void setPrice (double p) {this.price=p;}
   public double getCash ( ) { return cash;}
   public void setCash (double c) {this.cash=c;}

   public double computeChange( ) {return cash-price; }
   public int intcomputeChange( ) {return (int) (cash*100-price*100); }
   public int toDollars ( ) {return (int)computeChange(); }
   public int aChanges ( ) {return  intcomputeChange() % 100; }
   public int toQuarters ( ) {return aChanges() / 25; }
   public int bChanges ( ) {return aChanges() % 25; }
   public int toDimes ( ) {return bChanges() / 10; }
   public int cChanges ( ) {return bChanges() % 10; }
   public int toNickels ( ) {return cChanges() / 5; }  
   public int dChanges ( ) {return cChanges() % 5; }   
   public int toPennies ( ) {return dChanges() / 1; }
   public int eChanges (  ) {return dChanges() % 1; }      
   }
   ```

Comment: Really, this won't work.  If you're storing the dollar amount in `double` fields, why would you divide by 100 to convert to dollars?  On the other hand, if you're storing a number of cents, why wouldn't you just use `int` instead of `double`.

Comment: Thanks Kartic, I ran the code and the only problem that occurs is when the change is given it shows.
i.e:
Enter the price of the item: 
25.25
Enter cash amount: 
30.00
Change: 4.75
Dollar bills is: 0.0475
Quarters is: 0.19
Dimes is: 0.475
Nickels is: 0.95
Pennies is: 4.75

Comment: Sorry for that, I didn't look into the code. Just to highlight that he is not calling parameterized constructor, I have changed the code. Also I don't have much idea on dollar and cent. That's why I've mentioned, you have to change method body.

Comment: I got the basic understanding of Quarters, Dimes and updated my answer.

Comment: Yeah, that looks much better now.  I have removed my downvote.

Comment: As far as I can see, the only problem now is the floating point error in `intcomputeChange()`.